# Java - How to add numbers over time?

Tags: java

```
<pre> import java.util.*;

public class Test {
private static int StartingMoney = 1000;
private static int MaxMoney = 10000;
private static int Add = 100;
static Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(StartingMoney != MaxMoney){
            System.out.println("1:Add Money");
            int userInput = question.nextInt();
                if(userInput == 1){
                    System.out.println(StartingMoney + Add);
                }

        }
    }

}
 <code>
```

The goal of this code is to add a number until it reaches a certain amount, and the user will be able to choose whether or not he or she can add numbers to their current amount they have.  The output is always 1100

Comment: Something else to consider is that you should probably not give variables uppercase names, since that _typically_ means it refers to a class, not a variable.

Answer (score 10):

By doing `System.out.println(StartingMoney + Add);` you are only printing the value to the console and not changing your actual `StartingMoney` variable and this will still be `1000`.

Your program will go in an infinite loop as the condition `StartingMoney != MaxMoney` will never be reached.

You should be doing this instead:

```
StartingMoney += Add;
System.out.println(StartingMoney);
```

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    private static int StartingMoney = 1000;
    private static int MaxMoney = 10000;
    private static int Add = 100;
    private static Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(StartingMoney != MaxMoney){
            System.out.println("1: Add Money");
            int userInput = question.nextInt();
            if(userInput == 1) {
                /* Note the change here */
                StartingMoney += Add;
                System.out.println(StartingMoney);
            }
        }
    }
}
```